# Statistics of algorithm AB testing on occurrences only

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, recommender-system, ab-test

I have AB testing in place and I have to compare the data but I have no clue which statistical test to use.

I'll try to speak in dating app terms because I think it makes it easier to understand.

I have a dating app which works based on communities. Each community has its own users which can only interact with users from that community, and based on interactions in that community dataset for recommender is created.

For each community, in AB testing users are split into groups equally (one user is always in one group) and each group has its own recommender algorithm.

In dating app terms, informations I have are `profile visit`, `message` and `date` between two users. So only occurrence is tracked.

**End goal:**
I want to know if there is a test which can show if one algorithm results in more interactions than the other in most communities based only on interaction occurrence.

**Tried:**
I thought of using chi-square but I have no information on lack of occurrence and I'm not sure how to incorporate different communities into this.

Comment: By occurrence do you mean if two users interacted or not, or how many times they interacted? But you do not know if the interaction led to anything? They could have just been talking about the weather for an hour? And you wish to test if one group had more interactions than another?

Comment: @user2974951 I track how many times two users interacted and which type of interaction it is {`profile visit`, `message`, `date`}. The most valuable interaction and end goal is `date` (regardless of the outcome of the date), so I think it is better to take unique triplets of `(user1, user2, interaction_type)` as occurrence . I wish to know: if one group had more interactions than the other, and if one group had more Interactions of type X than the other.